# Add values to an html form elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two text boxes in my html document and I would like to assign values to them using JavaScript. I have text that I want to output to these two text boxes. How would I do this?

Comment: if by "text boxes" you mean `<input type="text" ...>` then you can change the value using the `value` property of the `input`

Comment: <input type="text" name="clue"><br>

Comment: That is what I have in my HTML document for the textbox, so what part would I change so that it will read the values from my JavaScript?

Comment: This is something that is very easily researched on the web. You are really expected to have exhausted research efforts before asking questions here

Comment: `read the values from my javascript` - you mean, so javascript can write values to the input, an input wont "read from javascript"

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('clue')[0].value = 'your text goes here';`

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("clue")[0].value = "some text";` assuming that element is the first to have that name in document.

Comment: `<input type'text' id='idOne' >`

`document.getElementById('idOne').value ='Lasan Pyaaz Dhaniya Adrak'`

Comment: not exactly the same @AndrewLi :p the correct way to do something is correct, I guess :p

Comment: please try to have some research before posting Questions

Comment: @Chetan - if that's how you feel, why answer? :D

Comment: @JaromandaX - i understand, but thought of it would demoralize him. So, gave answer, with comment. i know how it feels if someone gave you negative comment. I hope you understand. Answer will boost his confidence of learning things. i hope :)

Comment: @Chetan - I get what you're saying

Comment: you can simply use `value property` then why did you use javascript
`<input type="text" value="something" />`

Comment: @Chetan I understand you and also jaromanda-x, But as you said, SO is not a place for these entry level basic questions. here we are supposed to do all our research and if we did not find any way, SO would be our last hope. This question is like the the OP did not know anything at all about JavaScript and did not try anything and the first place he looked at was here. This is not right at all...

Comment: @EhsanT - Agreed, will keep in mind before answering these question. Also i feel that, this is spoon feeding, before posting any question, need basic research and effort that seems zero in this case. one Up vote for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use value property of input element -

```js
document.getElementById("user").value = "user name";
document.getElementById("email").value = "sample@gmail.com";
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" id="user"/>
<br/>
<input type="email" id="email">
</div>
```